# R: wide to long and fill dates

Tags: r, reshape

```
week = seq(as.Date("2022-9-1"), as.Date("2022-10-1"), by="weeks")
visits = c("[1,2,6,4,6,11,19]", "[12,2,7,8,6,11,22]", 
       "[8,2,5,8,4,15,13]", "[9,2,7,4,6,11,7]", 
       "[25,34]")
data = data.frame(week, visits)
```

The above data frame records daily visit in a string column, and each row represents a week.

I would like to convert the above dataset to a long table with daily visits. This is the expected output:

| date | visits |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-9-1 | 1 |
| 2022-9-2 | 2 |
| 2022-9-3 | 6 |
| 2022-9-3 | 6 |
| .... |  |
| 2022-9-30 | 34 |

I have tried the following steps: (1) break down the string using `strsplit` and remove the first and last item (which is `[` and `]`); (2) store each day's visit in separate columns; (3) use `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::complete` to fill the dates between weeks; (4) then loop over each first day of the week to make each week's wide data to long data. All these add to 60ish lines of code, where I feel that there might be an easier solution.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  mutate(visits = str_remove_all(visits, "\\]|\\[")) %>% 
  separate_rows(visits) %>%
  group_by(week) %>% 
  mutate(date = seq(first(week), length.out = n(), 
     by = '1 day'), .before = 'week') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-week)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 30 × 2
   date       visits
   <date>     <chr> 
 1 2022-09-01 1     
 2 2022-09-02 2     
 3 2022-09-03 6     
 4 2022-09-04 4     
 5 2022-09-05 6     
 6 2022-09-06 11    
 7 2022-09-07 19    
 8 2022-09-08 12    
 9 2022-09-09 2     
10 2022-09-10 7     
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you kindly please explain how does `str_remove_all(visits, "\\]|\\["))` work? Does it mean remove "the last ]" OR "the first ["?

Comment: I ran the code and it gave me an error `"Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs."`. It's at the last fourth line.

Comment: @RachelZhang It is just to remove both the `[`, `]`.  The error is not clear as `mutate` is from `dplyr` and I used `n()` within mutate

Comment: @RachelZhang can you try on a fresh R session.  Also what is the `packageVersion('dplyr')`